# What is a good way to store hydrogen?

Tags: science-based

I am interested in using electrolysis of water to generate hydrogen.  I believe I have three good renewable sources of electricity (solar, wind and hydro).  To start, I intend to put a little electric generator on the stream in my farm and slowly convert that energy to hydrogen for use in a converted propane generator to generate electricity.

Capturing the hydrogen will be easy, but what is the best way to store the accumulated hydrogen gas?

Comment: Carry water around and only generate hydrogen when you need it ASAP. Pure hydrogen is highly explosive.

Comment: Chemists and chemical engineers know well how to store hydrogen. Ask there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Renan: Pure hydrogen is not explosive, not even a little. *Mixtures* of hydrogen and oxygen are explosive. So you may carry hydrogen around all day long provided you make sure that it does not escape and mix with the oxygen in the air; this may be somewhat difficult, but the difficulty is mitigated by the natural tendency of hydrogen to go up up up.

Comment: There is no good way to store large quantities of hydrogen.  You need either high pressure or extreme refrigeration.  Besides, you lose considerable energy in using electricity to produce H2, then burning it to generate electricity again.  Much better to use the electricity directly, with perhaps battery backup.

Answer (score 0):

Hydrogen can be stored in two ways:
As a compressed gas in high-pressure tanks (beware, highly flammable!)
As a superliquid (the catch is it has to be at around -260 degrees Celsius, so you'd be wasting more energy than you got.)
Perhaps you should consider harnessing it at the moment you split the water, instead of storing it. Or use those forms of renewable energy mentioned earlier.

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm, but generally it's frowned upon to answer off-topic questions like this one, in case it encourages people to ask more of them.